# Bootstrap slider bar error slider is not defined

Tags: bootstrap-slider

I use the slider from [github](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider) and decided to use 1 example from [here](http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/).
Controller does not reset, an error:

```
individual_task_3.HTML code:32 Uncaught ReferenceError: slider is not defined
```

and points to the line

```
var slider = new Slider('ex1', {
```

Markup:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Индивидуальное задание 3</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="../css/bootstrap-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="../index.html">Дегтярев Данил | Компьютерная геометрия и графика</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="../index.html">Главная</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="individual_task_menu.html">Индивидуальные задания</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Индивидуальное задание 3</li>
    </ol>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Индивидуальное задание</h1>
        <p><h4>Задание: </h4>Добавить слайдер для плавного изменения цвета каждой вершины треугольника на цвет соседней вершины</p>
        <input id="ex1" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="14"/>
            <canvas id="canvas3D">Ваш браузер не поддерживает элемент canvas</canvas>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var slider = new Slider('ex1', {
            formatter: function(value) {
                return 'Current value: ' + value;
            }
        });
    </script>
    <script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        varying highp vec4 vColor;
          void main(void) {
            gl_FragColor = vColor;
          }
    </script>
    <script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
        attribute vec3 aVertexColor;
        varying highp vec4 vColor;
        void main(void) {
            gl_Position = vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
            vColor = vec4(aVertexColor, 1.0);
        }
    </script>       
    <script src="../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/three.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/canvas_style.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/individual task/individual_task_3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap-slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

All the libraries are installed and correct

Comment: `slider` is not defined would be your variable, not the `Slider`. It's hard to tell based on how much code you've shown.